# Correctly / Securely configuring Django for development on localhost

Tags: django, security, webserver, localhost

I'm developing a web app using Django. When I run the command `manage.py runserver`, I can access the website at `http://localhost (127.0.0.1:8000)`. Is there a security risk if I keep it running 24/7 while doing the development. Do I need to block this port on my router so that it isn't accessible from outside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no security risk since it runs in the localhost interface (127.0.0.1) so it is accessible only from your computer.

There would be a security risk only if you were running it to the 0.0.0.0 interface (manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000).

To elaborate a little more on my answer: When a an application that listens for connections (the django development server for instance) wants to run it must define the interface (IP) and the port (TCP) that it wants to bind to - meaning where it will start listening for new connections.

Now, all computers have an interface named localhost with the IP address 127.0.0.1. This is the loopback interface and it does not need any actual hardware to be enabled. Only clients running from the same computer can connect to this interface. So if you start a number of servers that are *only* bound to 127.0.0.1 you are completely safe and shouldn't worry about safety.

Beyond the localhost interface, your computer can have a number of other network interfaces, each one with one - or more - IPs. Let's take a case where you have for instance two network cards in your computer that are connected to two different networks: One with an IP of 192.168.1.1 and the other with an ip if 192.168.2.1. When you start a server you can bind it to the IP 192.168.1.1, so only computers from the network 192.168.1.x will be able to connect to it or to the IP 192.168.2.1 so that only computers from the network 192.168.2.x will be able to connect to it. Also, you may bind it to the 0.0.0.0 IP which means that it will accept connections from *all* interfaces !

I must say that I am not a network engineer so the terminology might not be 100% correct.

I hope it is more clear now if you have any questions just ask !

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me to a source where I can dig a level deeper ... for my understanding.

Comment: Well interface and port binding is not a django-specific topic but more network related. I will elaborate some more in my answer here.

Comment: Pyramid framework recommends `server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)` here http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/about . Is that unsafe then?

Comment: Even Django says here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/ `To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled)` - How do you make that secure?

Comment: Yes, make_server('0.0.0.0') would be unsecured. Other machines in your network would be able to connect to your server. You don't want to do this for non-production servers, but you can do it under a controlled environment (for instance to show your work to some of your peers).

Comment: The django documentation says that you will bind to the specific interface or 0.0.0.0 if you want your server to be viewable from other machines. In normal cases you would just bind to 127.0.0.1 so it will be only visible from your PC.